# Query send buffer usage on a socket in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

Is it possible to query how many bytes are in a socket's send buffer in linux?  I'd like to be able to query SO_SNDBUF with getsockopt to get the buffer size and then [insert technique here] to get the actual usage, which will let me know how much I'm filling up the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `SO_SNDBUF` does. `SO_SNDBUF` *sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes* (quoting [`socket(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)). You could probably use the `SIOCOUTQ` or `TIOCOUTQ` ioctls if you're using [tcp](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html) or [udp](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/udp.7.html).

**However, it's highly unlikely this is the right approach**. Have you considered using a select-like mechanism to notify you when a socket is writable ? Combined with nonblocking behavior it could be the ticket to a clean approach.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't 100% clear, I want to use SO_SNDBUF to get the total buffer size when I create the socket, and then monitor how much of that's actually _in use_ at any given time.  This is for a message queue type of application and I want to monitor things to make sure my queue's not slowly filling up due to a slow reader.  I think SIOCOUTQ is exactly what I need.